# Creating Boxplot using groupby

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, seaborn

I have a df which consists of two columns, 'date' and 'value', containing multiple years data of 'value.'  I'd like to create a boxplot of the range of values grouped by month and year.   I use groupby to group the values as such:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%b%Y'))['value']
```

But now I cannot figure out how to operate on the resulting groupby data structure to create the boxplot (via either matplotlib or seaborn).  Stumped.

Comment: [`boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) already groups data with the `by` keyword. For further help can you give exemple data as reproducible code?

Comment: How should I do this?   The data consists of a series of floats, over 4 calendar years.

Comment: You can do this with ```df.to_dict()```, and then we can copy and paste that into our console.

Comment: Apologies, not as sophisticated as you. I am using Juypter notebook, the output for df.to_dict() gets pasted to an output window and is quite long.  Do you wish me to paste this into the question box?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your dataframe looks like it was generated by the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2019-1-1', periods=1000, freq='D'), 
                   'value': np.random.randint(0,10,size=1000)})
```

It looks like this:

```
          date  value
0   2019-01-01      3
1   2019-01-02      9
2   2019-01-03      2
3   2019-01-04      2
4   2019-01-05      4
..         ...    ...
995 2021-09-22      3
996 2021-09-23      5
997 2021-09-24      1
998 2021-09-25      4
999 2021-09-26      8
```

Now you can compute a new column `month`:

```py
df['month'] = df.date.dt.month
```

```
          date  value  month
0   2019-01-01      3      1
1   2019-01-02      9      1
2   2019-01-03      2      1
3   2019-01-04      2      1
4   2019-01-05      4      1
..         ...    ...    ...
995 2021-09-22      3      9
996 2021-09-23      5      9
997 2021-09-24      1      9
998 2021-09-25      4      9
999 2021-09-26      8      9
```

And call `boxplot` using this new column as grouper:

```py
df.boxplot('value', by='month')
```

Answer (score 0):

parse_dates your time series Date column and set it as the index. Use pd.Grouper and level 0 to access the index and set the frequency to D or daily.  The boxplot will find the min and max frequency and median and outliers based on the grouped.index.year

```
df=pd.read_csv('sp500.csv',parse_dates=['Date'],index_col='Date')
grouped=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0,freq='D'))['Open'].mean()

sns.boxplot(x=grouped.index.year, y=grouped.values,
data=grouped)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby using the datetime accessor [`to_period()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) with a monthly frequency.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2019-1-1', periods=1000, freq='D'), 
                   'value': np.random.randint(0,10,size=1000)})

df.groupby(df.date.dt.to_period("M")).boxplot(subplots=False, rot=90)
```

[image]